# Ошибка в программе на C++

Tags: c++

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char obr[15];
    char fam[15];
    char name[15];
    char tel[10];
    char p[20];
    int n = 0;
    puts("File name:");
    scanf("%s", &p);
    f = fopen(p, "rt");
    puts("Enter surname:");
    scanf("%s", &obr);
    while (!feof(f))
    {
        fscanf(f, "%s %s %s", &fam, &name, &tel);
        if (fam == obr)
        {
            printf("%s %s %s", fam, name, tel);
            n++;
        }
    }
    if (n) { printf("Number of records: %i\n", n); }
    else { printf("No data. %i", n); }
    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
}
```

Помогите найти ошибку в коде, в ходе выполнения программы счётчик n=0, хотя у меня в блокноте есть такая запись "Ivanov Vasya 900-90-90". Суть программы: если в блокноте есть фамилия, совпадающая с той, которую вводит пользователь, то мы выводит данные, связанные с этой фамилией, и считаем количество найденных записей, т.е. n.

Comment: А в чем именно ошибка? Код есть, а ошибки нет... Приведите частичный пример содержимого файла и что вы вводите в консоли.

Comment: Если бы писали на плюсах, а не на си, и использовали тип std::string, то сравнение прошло бы хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim По-моему, нужно сочинять FAQ :) Этот вопрос - о сравнении указателей вместо содержимого - постоянная беда.

Comment: да, и в нем должны быть ссылки на реальные бумажные книги с указанием страниц и номеров строк.

Comment: @KoVadim я и так писал на С++, ориентируясь на книгу "С/C++ в задачах и примерах" Н. Культина 2002 года.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо этого цикла

```
#include <string>
         ^^^^^^^

//...

while (!feof(f))
{
    fscanf(f, "%s %s %s", &fam, &name, &tel);
                         ^^^   ^^^    ^^^ 
    if (fam == obr)
        ^^^^^^^^^^ 
    {
        printf("%s %s %s", fam, name, tel);
        n++;
    }
}
```

напишите

```
#include <cstring>
         ^^^^^^^

//...

while ( fscanf(f, "%s %s %s", fam, name, tel) == 3 )
                             ^^^  ^^^   ^^^
{
    if ( strcmp( fam, obr) == 0)
        ^^^^^^^^^^ 
    {
        printf("%s %s %s", fam, name, tel);
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло, но теперь попрошу Вас объяснить, что было не так, я не могу остаться равнодушным к изучению языка

Comment: @MartinEden Я выделил в своем ответе штрихом, что было неправильно. Например, заголовок ,string> - это стандартный заголовок C++ дл объявления класса std::string, в то время как функция strcmp, используемая в программе, объявлена в стандартном C заголовке, который в C++ записывается как <cstring>

Comment: т.е. с адресами переменных сделать не получится?

Comment: @MartinEden Спецификатор формата %s ждет аргумент типа char *, а не типа char **.

Comment: @MartinEden Также сравнивать надо не адреса строк, так как они очевидно различны, а сами строки.

Comment: об этом не знал, выполнял по подобию книги "С/C++ в задачах и примерах" Н. Культина 2002 года, там постоянно используются адреса строк

Comment: @MartinEden Я не имел дело с этой книгой, но, скорей всего, если это действительно так, то имеет место ошибка.